# Can't move chrome tabs to new window in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

For some reason as of yesterday I'm unable to switch Google Chrome tabs between monitors. When I drag a tab from one screen to other, the window appears to freeze, necessitating an alt-tab, which then maximises the window again on the same monitor it was on previously.

Has anything changed in an update or have I switched on a setting somewhere?

Edit: In fact scratch the "between monitors" part, I can't even drag tabs off one window to a new one without it locking up, the tab appears to crash the moment it detaches from the main window.

Edit2:  The more I experiment the more problems I see, tabs seem to be locking up a huge amount, opening new windows has the same effect. I've disabled all chrome extensions but that didn't help

More updates: The issue is sporadic. Sometimes I am able to drag the tab across 2/3 times before it starts crashing again. The drag action seems to have more performance issues than it used to though when it works. I am nowhere near my CPU/RAM caps.

Comment: A re-install did not help, running low on ideas.

Comment: I was able to do this in my tests, which indicates, a system level problem.

Comment: Right, thoughts on how to go about debugging? I tried the same action with IE and Firefox and they worked fine.

Comment: Uninstall first, then perform a fresh install of Chrome. A re-install does not necessarily replace corrupt Chrome files.

Comment: thats what I did, also deleted the AppData folders etc